# Algorithm about number theory

Tags: c++, algorithm

Give two positive integer a,b (1<=a<=30, 1<=b<=10000000) ,and define two unrepeatable set L and R,

```
L = {x * y | 1 <= x <= a, 1 <= y <= b, x,y is integer}

R = {x ^ y | 1 <= x <= a, 1 <= y <= b, x,y is integer},
```

^ is XOR operate

For any two integer: A∈L, B∈R, we format B to n+1(n is the decimal digit number of b) decimal digit(fill 0 in front of B),and then joint B to the end of A and get a new integer AB.

Compute the sum of all generated integer AB (In case the sum exceed, just return  "sum mod 1000000007", mod means modular operation)

**Note: the time of your algorithm is no more than 3 seconds**

**My algorithm** is very simple:we can easily get the max number in set R, and the element in R is 0,1,2,3...maxXor,(the element max(a,b) may be not in R), using a hash table the compute set L. **But the algorithm consume 4 seconds when a = 30, b = 100000**.

---

Give an example:

```
a = 2, b = 4, so

L = {1 * 1, 1 * 2, 1 * 3, 1 * 4, 2 * 1, 2 * 2, 2 * 3, 2 * 4} =  {1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 8}

R =  {1^1,1^2,1^3,1^4,2^1,2^2,2^3,2^4} =  {0, 1, 2, 3, 5, 6}
```

All generated integer AB is:

```
{

100, 101, 102, 103, 105, 106,

200, 201, 202, 203, 205, 206,

300, 301, 302, 303, 305, 306,

400, 401, 402, 403, 405, 406,

600, 601, 602, 603, 605, 606,

800, 801, 802, 803, 805, 806

}
```

The **sum** of all **AB** is `14502`

Comment: You'll need to post your code so people can see what (if anything) is being done wrong.

Comment: Maybe you should define performance requirements in terms of compkexity, because, you know, I have a nice supercomputer and  it does it in less than 3 sec anyway

Comment: @dkrikun It sounds like a problem from a programming competition - these typically use a mid-range computer and **don't** give time complexity requirements.

Comment: How are you building the set L? Please show your code.

Comment: @splrs I psot my code

Comment: @AbhishekBansal I made a mistake, the set R can be easily computed in O(1), but computing L consume much time

Comment: @dkrikun I didn't show clearly.What Dukeling say is my viewpoint

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about reviewing code, maybe.  I can't tell.  But not OT here.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

So the number AB can be written as `10^(n+1) A + B`. Which means that summing over all `A, B`, the total is equal to

```
|R| 10^(n+1) Sum(A in L) + |L| Sum(B in R)
```

In your example,

```
|L| = 6
|R| = 6
Sum(A in L) = 24
Sum(B in R) = 17
n = 3
```

which when plugged into the above formula gives 14,502.

This reduces the runtime in the size of the sets from quadratic to linear, so you should see quite a huge improvement.

The next bits I haven't fleshed out fully because I don't have the time to, but they feel like they should work:

- First, notice that `Sum(A in L)` would be trivial to calculate using

  ```
  1 + 2 + .. + n = n(n-1)/2
  ```

  if there wasn't the constraint that `L` doesn't contain repeats. You can get around this though by exploiting the fact that `a` is very small: iteratively calculate the sums `1, .., a` using the triangular number formula and use that information to avoid counting a product more than once.
- For `Sum(B in R)`, notice that when you compare `y` and `x^y`, at most the first `lg(a)` bits have changed. So you can split a sum of `x^y`s into two sums: one which deals with the bits from `lg(a)+1` upwards and which depends only on `b`, and a second, more complex sum which deals with the bits from `lg(a)` downwards and which depends on `a` and `b`.

Edit: The OP's asked me to expand on how to quickly compute `Sum(A in L)`. There was a lottt of stuff in this section in previous edits, but I've actually sat down and worked through it now rather than haphazardly batting it around in my head. It also turned out to be more complicated than I expected, so my apologies for not sitting down and working through it sooner @tenos.

So what we want to do is take the sum of all distinct products `x*y` such that `1 <= x <= a` and `1 <= y <= b`. Well, that turns out to be pretty hard so let's start with a simpler problem: given two integers `x1, x2` with `x1 < x2`, how can we compute the sum of all distinct products `x1*y` or `x2*y` where `1 <= y <= b`?

If we dropped the distinctness criterion, this'd be easy: it'd simply be

```
x1*Sum(b) + x2*Sum(b)
```

where `Sum(j)` denotes the sum of integers `1` through `j` inclusive, and can be calculated using Gauss's formula for the triangular numbers. So again we can reduce the problem into something simpler: how can we find the sum of all products that appear in both the left and right terms?

Well, two products are equal if

```
x1*y1 == x2*y2
```

This happens exactly when `x1*y1 == x2*y2 == k*LCM(x1, x2)`, where `LCM` is the [lowest common multiple](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Least_common_multiple) and `k` is some integer.

The sum of this over all `k` such that `1 <= k*LCM(x1, x2) <= x1*b` is

```
R(x1, x2) = LCM(x1, x2) * Sum(x1*b/LCM(x1, x2))
```

where `R` stands for "repeats". Which means that our sum of all distinct products `x1*y` or `x2*y` where `1 <= y <= b` is

```
x1*Sum(b) + x2*Sum(b) - R(x1, x2)
```

Next, let's extend the definition of `R` to be defined on three variables `x1 < x2 < x3` as

```
R(x1, x2, x3) = LCM(x1, x2, x3) * Sum(x1*b/LCM(x1, x2, x3))
```

and similarly for 4 variables, 5 variables, etc. Then the sum of distinct products for three `x1 < x2 < x3` is

```
x1*Sum(b) + x2*Sum(b) + x3*Sum(b) - R(x1, x2) - R(x1, x3) - R(x2, x3) + R(x1, x2, x3)
```

by the [inclusion-exclusion principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combinatorial_principles#Inclusion-exclusion_principle).

So, let's make use of this. Define

```
Sum for x = 1: 1*Sum(b)
Sum for x = 2: 2*Sum(b) - R(2, 1)
Sum for x = 3: 3*Sum(b) - R(3, 2) - R(3, 1) + R(3, 2, 1)
```

Etc. Then the sum of all these sums up to `x = a` is the sum of all distinct products.

Edit: @tenos turned this into a useful solution. He noticed that since i*Sum(b) contains many repeats, we can replace by i*sum(k...b), k = max(b/minPrimeFactor(i) + 1, i).

Further, when using inclusion-exclusion principle, many unnecessary computations can be pruned. For instance, if R(1,2) = NULL, there is no need to compute R(1,2,3), R(1,2,4).., etc. In fact, when b is very big, there are many R(i,..j) = NULL.

Comment: Thanks for answer. The elements int set L is not continuous, so sum(L) = 1 + 2 + .. + n = n(n-1)/2 doesn't work. By the way ,I don't understand "factor each number in 1, .., a into primes and use that information to avoid counting a product more than once".

Comment: When a = 4, b = 6 ,and compute L with your method: 1*(1...6), 2*(4,5,6), 3*(3,4,5,6), 4*(4,5,6),  but 2*6 and 3*4 both equal 12. L still contain repeats.

Comment: Actually, I do not catch you clearly. you said exclude multiples of k up to k*b, which means I should record and save the computed products.I think it is the same way to compute all the product and use a hash-table to avoid repeats.I will be very thankful if you can give the computing process of "a = 6, b = 9".

Comment: Hi Andy, I have thought for a long time, but I still didn't figure out. Let's consider the example `a = 6, b = 9`, we compute `1*(1,...,9), 2*(5,...,9), 3*(4,...,9), 4*(5,...,9), 5*(5,...,9), 6*(6,...,9)`. As you said when a product has computed, we must exclude it in the next computing process. So when 4*9 has computed, we must exclude `36` int the next around ,so we must save `4*9`, which means we must save all the product which has computed in order to avoid repeats.And you said triangle number formula, I didn't figure out where I can use it.I hope for your reply. Thank you very much.

Comment: @tenos Posted a more rigorous approach. Turned out to be more complicated than I thought. Will code it up and test it myself tomorrow afternoon, but I said I'd have something for you by the morning so figured I'd give you what's working on the instances I've done by hand. Wait for me to test it properly first though if you can, would rather not waste any more of your time if it's wrong.

Comment: Hello Andy, I have test your method. It turns out to be true. But its  efficency is not very well for the computation of all the `combination(a, i) (i = 2...a)`, when `a = 30`, the calculated amount is very large.

Comment: Yeah, you'll get a number of terms in `combination(a, i)` quadratic in `a` in the sum for `30`, which will be ~1000 in practice. Thing is, ~900 might be a lot, but when `b` can range up to 10,000,000 it's comparatively very small.

Comment: When `a = 30` and `b >= 30`, only `combination(30,15) = 155117520`,but the `max of b is `10000000``, so your method cost more time than the method which using hash-table. May be there are some other more efficient ways to solve this.

Comment: Argh. Yeah, just read up on it and inclusion-exclusion suffers from a combinatorial explosion, it's not quadratic at all. Rats. That would also explain why during my extensive googling, I couldn't find any solution better than "calculate all products and sum the distinct ones".

Comment: Well hasn't this been a wild goose chase. Do you have any ideas on how to do this better?

Comment: For the moment, I didn't come up with a better approach. If find one, I will improve this question. By the way, thanks for all your answers.

Comment: No problem. Sorry for the runaround on all this, when I first looked at it it seemed much easier than it turned out to be.

Comment: Hi,Andy,I Have solve this problem. Your method is right. I using some tricks to pruning some unnecessary caculation.

Comment: Would you mind updating the OP with your solution if you get a chance? It'd be great to finally see a solution to this thing.

Comment: Edited your edit in because the SO review queue saw fit to reject it -_-. Nice work, thanks for sharing!